# How to redesign a database to find distinct values more effectively?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I often have a need to select a set of distincs values from a column with low selectivity in a big table while joining it to some other table where I can't really filter the entries in the resulting set to some reasonable amount.

For example, I have a table with 20M rows, with column someID which has 200 unique values. I join this table with some other result set on another column and filter 20M rows down to, say, 10M rows (still a lot), and then need to find distinct someID. So I end up with a 10M rows scan no matter what, which is a pain.

In this join, there is no way to filter the results more, 10M records is really the set I need to find distint someID in.

Is there any standard approach to redesign the tables or create some additional table to make this work better?

Comment: I guess this someID is a foreign key to another table, but you can't just select from the foreign table because you only want 'active' ID's, right? How often is the transactional/large table changed? How variable is this query you're using to find them? Have you checked the query plan? The only alternative design I can think of is to have some kind of pre calced summary table which would only be feasible if latency isn't an issue.

Comment: How about an index on (join_column, someID)?

Comment: Nick.McDermaid, yes, someID is an FK to another table, but I need to only select someIDs from the resulting set after the join. Both tables change quite often. The query is a stored procedure with an input parameter based on which the join is performed. Query plan shows index scan (i.e. it scans the whole 20M rows table, which I think is the only way to go here) and a hash join. How would you go about creating such a table? This is probably what I'd need, but I can't see what I'd need to calculate there.

Answer (score 2):

Your basic query is:

```
select distinct t1.someID
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.col1 = t2.col1;
```

The optimal indexes for this query are `table1(col1, someId)` and `table2(col1)`.

Here is another version of the query:

```
select distinct t1.someId
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t1.col1 = t2.col1);
```

In this case, the optimal index would be `table1(someid, col1)`.  It is possible that SQL Server will be intelligent in this case and stop looking for an `exists` value when it encounters a match (although I am a bit skeptical).  You would have to investigate the execution plans generated on your data.

Another idea extends this even further:

```
select s.someId
from someIdtable s
where exists (select 1
              from table1 t1 join
                   table2 t2
                   on t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.someId = s.someId);
```

This removes the outer distinct, depending only on the semi-join in the `exists` clause.  The optimal index would be `table1(someid, col1)`.

Under some circumstances, this version would probably have the best performance -- for instance, if all the `someIds` were in the result set.  On the other hand, if very few are, this might have poor performance.

Comment: Just found your blog @Gordon - most interesting :)

Comment: SQL Server _will_ stop executing the EXISTS subquery when it finds the first match. Not sure if it's actually officially documented somewhere, though.

Comment: @dean this statement is not true in general. The optimizer has many strategies for deal with EXISTS (which is just a form of a join). There is specific execution policy for EXISTS.

Comment: @usr In general, the evaluation of EXISTS will stop when the first match is found, optimizer is clever enough. I'm not sure what you meant with 'specific execution policy', but if you have a sample you can share, I'd really like to see it (could also move it offline). Thx.

Comment: @dean exists can be implemented using a hash join. Both inputs will be consumed and hash-matched fully with no skipping at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm stealing the "basic query" from Gordons answer:

```
select t1.someID
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1
group by t1.someID
```

This query fits the requirements of indexed views. You can index this query. Running it will result in a simple clustered index scan which is as cheap as it gets.